# Range.Find does not find exactly what I'm searching for

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot understand what is the issue with this code? Can any expert be able to explain and advise me how to solve this problem and your help will be very much appreciated.

Below is the code, My understanding is, this will find exact the what you want to find, like example, I would like to `find = "Mistral Disney USB Fan MRF500PH"`, and I very sure that, there is no this product name is the search range, But somehow it return me `SkipProductName` `"Mistral Disney USB Fan MRF500PHB"` which is not correct. `SkipProductName` should return me as `Nothing`.

```
Set SkipProductName = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Sheet1XTotalProductName, 2)).Find(ProductName1)
```

This is correct example A, SkipProductName return as nothing which is correct.

https://ibb.co/XYVd8w8
https://ibb.co/WvL4QC4

This is the problem, `SkipProductName` returns as `"Mistral Disney USB Fan MRF500PHB"` but my search `ProductName1 = "Mistral Disney USB Fan MRF500PH"`. `SkipProductName` returns `nothing` like the example A above.
https://ibb.co/Dw0PQjQ
https://ibb.co/pzXRSWd

Comment: The [LookAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find#:~:text=xlComments%2C%20or%20xlCommentsThreaded.-,LookAt,be%20one%20of%20the%20following%20XlLookAt%20constants%3A%20xlWhole%20or%20xlPart.,-SearchOrder) argument in `Find` might be `xlPart`. Some settings in `Find` are saved and if you don't specify those argument, it will use the previously saved value so make sure you specify them always.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation of the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) reveals what your issue is:

> *The settings for* `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, *and* `MatchByte` *are saved each time you use this method. If you don't specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.*

You need to define those 4 parameters or VBA uses whatever was used by VBA or the search/replace dialog box before. Since you never know what your users did search/replace you end up with randomly working/non-working results if you don't specify all of those 4 parameters.

In your case you need at least to specify `.Find(What:=ProductName1, LookAt:=xlWhole)` to ensure it does not find a part of a cell but instead compares the full cell value.

---

**Off topic but important:**

In your code you specify `Worksheets("sheet1")` for `Range` but not for `Cells(2, 2)` and `Cells(Sheet1XTotalProductName, 2)`. This might easily run into erros as those cells are not necessarily in `Worksheets("sheet1")` if you don't specify them. If the active sheet is not `Worksheets("sheet1")` this code will fail!

```
Set SkipProductName = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Sheet1XTotalProductName, 2)).Find(ProductName1)
```

**Always** specify in which worksheet your `Range`, `Cells`, `Columns`, `Rows` objects are@

```
Set SkipProductName = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(2, 2), Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Sheet1XTotalProductName, 2)).Find(ProductName1)
```

Or shorter using `With`

```
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(Sheet1XTotalProductName, 2)).Find(ProductName1)
End With
' note the leading dot .Cells makes it use the `With` statement!
```

or even better

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")

ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(Sheet1XTotalProductName, 2)).Find(ProductName1)
```

Never let Excel guess which worksheet you mean!

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for the whole explanation, it really helps!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya If this answered your question please mark it as solution.

Comment: Sir, I am not OP, i just followed your solution to learn & apply, ! Although I have voted up!